# atbswp python file is not running on crontabs

Tags: python, linux, automation, cron, click

atbswp is a software that help you automate all the mouse clicks and movements and keyboards keys so you can automate everything u do and repeat it or replay it

and by using crontab you can schedule it so you can run automated sequence at specific time

the app extracts a python file
and you run it inside the app or in terminal without the need of the app

the problem is
when i run it in terminal it runs ok
when i put it in crontab to run it doesnt run and i got errors in the crontab log file

i really need help it is something amazing for everyone i think
this is the cron log error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/zultan/bot1", line 4, in 
import pyautogui
File "/home/zultan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyautogui/**init**.py", line 241, in 
import mouseinfo
File "/home/zultan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mouseinfo/**init**.py", line 223, in 
_display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 675, in **getitem**
raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DISPLAY'

Comment: Make sure you have the path to the executable on the crontab line i.e. /usr/bin/python3 "/pathtopythonfile"

Comment: Yes I made sure about that but I get that message

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution for everybody
put this
in the crontab -e

DISPLAY=:0

XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority